# JSONP how to retrieve text

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I do understand **what** JSON/JSONP does, but I'm not a programmer and do not know how to extract the bare basics for simple usage. I've read a lot on JSONP and lots of examples on various usage for JSONP, but I have yet to find a simple example for retrieving text from another page (e.g. `http://www.domain.com/external/text.aspx`).

Could somebody please give an example of a jQuery/JSONP setup for retrieving text into a div?
I would think that is a very basic use of JSONP.

Answer (score 13):

First, it's important to understand that for JSONP to work, the server must know that it's going to be contacted with a JSONP request. In other words, you can't just make a request to some random server and expect it to work if the server is not prepared properly.

If you do know of a server with a URL that is designed to accept and respond to JSONP requests, then what it will return to you is a JSON expression wrapped in a call to a function. Your page will include that function, and so when the results come back from the server the browser will interpret the JSON expression and then invoke the function.

Thus, if you want to make a service that returns a nice block of text, you'll invoke the service like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.domain.com/external/text.aspx?callback=", function(data) {
  $('#targetDiv').text(data.text);
});
```

The jQuery code will prepare everything such that the server will be told (via a parameter called "jsonp" in the HTTP request) the name of the function to call (and jQuery itself will build that function for you).  The server should respond with something like this:

```
jqueryFunctionName({text: "This is a nice block of text."})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving a straight forward example. I will hereby recommend you as the top candidate for the Nobel prize of pedagogy. You can also treat yourself with a cupcake ...or something.

One thing, just to be on the safe side:
I've put your code between <sript> tags just below the HTML div code. Also I have a link in the <head> tag to jquery-1.4.2.min.js. Is that right? If so, it didn't work and that means the server is not set up for JSONP. Right?

I maybe pushing the limit here, but can you also give an example on how to retrieve text through a proxy? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes yes - sorry, I wasn't trying to provide a complete page full of code. Yes, your jQuery call to fetch the JSON stuff would be inside a script tag, and probably inside some sort of handler for an event - maybe a response to a "click" or something.  As to proxies - assuming you mean an HTTP proxy - well there shouldn't be anything special at all; if you can get to the server from the browser for a normal URL, then you should have no problem.  There's nothing "weird" about the HTTP request for the JSON content.

Comment: Do I have to create the JSON file?

Comment: Well, *something* has to create it, and that something has to be on the server you contact.  Like I said, this isn't something you can just do to any random server out there: it has to already support JSONP interactions.