# How to get data from cross-site? I'm using $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-site

I'm testing a javascript code which is on localhost. This file requires data from a remote server in JSON format. When I directly hit the JSON url, I get the data, but in javascript, I'm getting empty response.

What might be the reason? I'm using jquery post method to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you cannot use AJAX to access a remote server. You have to use JSONP. If you don't have control of the other server, or if the other server doesn't offer JSONP, you have to use a proxy.

It's really easy to write one in PHP. http://www.betavine.net/bvportal/blog/view.html?blogId=101&postId=ff8080811afe49d3011afe4bb5de0003

```
<?
ob_start();

$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Owen's AJAX Proxy");

$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($curl_handle);
header("Content-Type: $content_type");
echo $content;
ob_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access any resource from different domain using JavaScript due to security reasons. jQuery cannot do anything for this but there are some ways to achieve this like `JSONP` or `YQL`.

Take a look at this quick tip for cross domain `AJAX` request with `YQL`.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` is an ajax method, and you can't use ajax methods to access data from a different origin.

See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for details:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 1):

There's a protective measure set up with JavaScript that you should look into.  It's the same origin policy.  Basically it means if you want to do an XmlHttpRequest for data from a server that isn't of the same origin that the page you are on, you can't, unless you jump through hoops.

Check out JSON-P, or jQuery's methods for overcoming this.

Answer (score 1):

Requesting data from a different domain is restricted as a security concern (see [*CORS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)), specifically to prevent XSS(cross site scripting) attacks.

You can try a couple of alternatives:

- [**JSONP**](http://json-p.org/) is an option if the other domain supports it
- [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499997/jsonp-how-to-retrieve-text) another relevant question

You can use [**YQL**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/) to request resources from another domain.

Apart from these alternatives you can always make a server proxy and have that proxy query the domain and return results.

Answer (score 1):

The server you are requesting from must either support [JSONP](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP&ei=U4MpT5TwBqOc2AWNo6HBAg&usg=AFQjCNF9iru2-pOWuj8FjOdl2X4WcsD3ZQ) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Otherwise, it is not possible.

It is also not possible to make a JSONP request using `POST`, it must be `GET`